# ORDER BY DESC gives wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this function which retrieves twwets from a certain user which are stored in a db. If I use ORDER BY ASC, like in the example, I get the right result, but if I use order by DESC the latest tweet is always omitted and missing in the array. Can't see why this is. All help much appreciated!

```
public static function getTweets($id, $order="created ASC") {


$dbh = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>    "SET NAMES utf8"));

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from tweet 
                 WHERE userid=:id 
                 ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . ""
                 );

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
$article = new Article( $row );
$list[] = $article;

}


 return $list;

}
```

Comment: you have a `$row = $stmt->fetch();` extra.

Comment: it looks like you are reading the first row, then reading all the rows in the while loop.  But, adding the rows that are read in the loop to $list.

Comment: Great, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line,

```
//$row = $stmt->fetch();

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
```